# Why are old RJ-11 modular telephone cables reversed?

Tags: cables, telephone

I've checked all my old modular phone cables and all of them have the terminal plugs attached so that the wiring is reversed.  That is plug 1 is Black-Red-Green-Yellow and at the other end of the cable Plug 2 is Yellow-Green-Red-Black.  This appears to have been a standard for voice telephones that plug into RJ-11 jacks.  I understand that polarity did not matter in old telephones, but I'd like to know why the cord wires are always reversed. Why was this done?

Comment: At least reversing the order makes possible systems where one pair of wires connects the input of device A to the output of device B and the output of device A is connected to the input of device B. Both devices can have the same wiring order which pins are for output and which are for input.

Comment: That must be the reason.  Thanks.